# iOS in-app purchase transactionReceipt vs. appStoreReceiptURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

We've been happily processing in-app purchases in our iOS app since the beginning of time. Because the code has been around a while, it uses the now-deprecated `transactionReceipt` property on the transaction we get when our `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` method is called by Store Kit. We send that receipt to our server, which validates it through a post to Apple's server, does what we need to do on the server, and reports back "success" to our app. Works great.

Now we want to add a subscription-based product so I'm looking at having to re-implement IAP using the `appStoreReceiptURL` property on the main bundle and loading my app receipt from there. There are a couple things I don't get.

First and most obvious: I get the same `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` state when `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` is called. For now, when I submit it to Apple I'm just displaying the JSON I get back. Since the status is non-zero I'm also submitting to the sandbox server and displaying what I get back from it, too. Problem is in both cases I get this:

`{"status":21002, "exception":"com.apple.jingle.mzfairplay.validators.DrmInvalidArgumentException"}`

I suspect this has something to do with the fact that I'm running a debug build, though not in the sim -- it's running on an actual device. To get around that, I tried uploading a build to the App Store so I could download through TestFlight, but since I'm using my sandbox Apple ID, TestFlight refuses to install it.

So the first question is why am I getting this "DrmInvalidArgumentException", and am I configured correctly to test (debug build on real device, using my sandbox Apple ID to make purchases).

Second question is more baffling to me. As I understand it, I will still get notified via `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions`, and I will iterate over the transactions I get there (?) but then instead of submitting the receipt in the transaction, I'll submit the app receipt from the URL in the main bundle. It will contain ALL IAP PURCHASES EVER and I will have to iterate over all those to figure out what's new and what I'm interested in, right?

The flow doesn't seem right. I'm getting a notification based on a transaction, but then looking at a dump of ALL my IAP transactions that are contained in the app receipt. So I can't possibly be understanding the flow correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Status 21002 is `The data in the receipt-data property was malformed or missing.`. The body of the POST to the verify endpoint has to be a JSON dict containing a `receipt-data` key and a `password` key that contains your app-specific shared secret that you can get from iTunes Connect.

You might try using [this tool](https://www.revenuecat.com/verify.html) to test your receipts. You don't need to use TestFlight, everything should work fine on a debug build as long as you are using a Sandbox iTunes account, which you can create in iTunes Connect.

Your explanation is correct, you will want to send the whole receipt for each purchased transaction. This is redundant, you could potentially keep a app side cache so you don't send the same receipt data each time but it is possible for the contents of `appStoreReceiptURL` to change at any time.

There are many other tricky edge cases implementing subscriptions. I built [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/) because of all these crappy things with subscriptions. Apple really bolted it onto the existing IAP stuff poorly in my opinion.

Comment: I haven't added my subscription yet -- I'm testing with existing products to verify I can handle what I'm already doing. I'm under the impression that the password is only needed if the dictionary contains an autorenewable subscription.

Comment: Ugh. Plus signs. Need to percent-encode the base64 string. Not sure why my other receipts have been going through OK. I'll take another look at RevenueCat, too.

Comment: Ah yeah, this is is how I encode the contents of the URL: `NSString *fetchToken = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];`. The RevenueCat implementation [is open source](https://github.com/revenuecat/purchases-ios) if you want to see how I do it.

Comment: I'm sending the receipt to the server as a parameter on a URL string, so the plus-signs are being interpreted as spaces.

FYI when I plugged my base64 string into your revenuecat tool to decode it, I couldn't scroll the result div on the right. Using Safari on OS X.

Comment: Oh, awesome, thanks for the tip! I only tried it with shorter receipts. You might not want to send it as a URL param since some webservers have a limit to the size a URL can be. This may not be the case anymore I'm not sure but I always `POST` receipts and put the payload in the body.

Comment: I have some other large URL strings I send for other reasons so I haven't worried about the length. Because of the move to the app receipt (which I assume can get huge) as opposed to individual transaction receipts, I'm going to have to change the way I post to the server. Since I control the server, I've just upped the max length of query strings. It's at least 4096 now. :-)

Comment: I have a receipt that is 9273 characters in Base64. It can grow quite rapidly especially if you have a short renewal period.

Comment: The problem is first time it worked for me on our php server, then next day I've again purchased test subscription and the same error as Craig. I've also noticed that receipt-Data change. The old one still works, however it only shows old purchases, not the new ones. I've also tested it on RevenueCat and the results are identical.